# Can't call DeleteObject in Entity framework - missing an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to delete an object in my asp.net MVC3/Code-first Entity Framework application, but I don't seem to have the necessary options, as it brings up a "does not contain a definition for DeleteObject" error.  Anyone know if I'm missing an assembly reference.  Here is my repository code:

```
private dbContext db = new dbContext();

public void DeleteAccessDetails(AccessDetails details)
{
     db.DeleteObject(details); //error here as DeleteObject isn't recognised
}
```

Here are my references:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MySite.Models;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.Entity;
```

I thought having System.Data.Entity would have been enough to bring up DeleteObject, but intellisense is hardly bringing up any options - only Dispose, Entry, SaveChanges and Set

Edit: Here is also my code for accessing the repository:

```
Repository rep = new Repository();
AccessDetails paymentUpdate = rep.GetPaymentByID(item.AccessDetailsTableID);
rep.DeleteAccessDetails(paymentUpdate);
```

Edit 2: Here is an image of my references folder:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Right enough, I don't have System.Data.Objects in my references folder.  When I looked in the Add Reference section (.NET tab) it wasn't there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for the DbContext in EF4.1 seems to show that it doesn't include a delete method on that class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.103).aspx...

This question looks similar - might be some help: [MVC 3 EF 4.1 dbContext - Deleting one-to-many data object with non-nullable foreign-key relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889886/mvc-3-ef-4-1-dbcontext-deleting-one-to-many-data-object-with-non-nullable-forei)

Comment: Cheers Dave - that second link provided the solution.  Many thanks

Answer (score 25):

`DbContext` does not have a `DeleteObject()` method. Instead of that, use the `Remove()` method to clear the object from the `DbSet`, then save the changes.

```
dbContext db = new dbContext(); // Arrange the context

Department dept = db.Departments.Single(p => p.Id == "1"); // Find the item to remove

db.Departments.Remove(dept); // Remove from the context

b.SaveChanges(); // Delete from the database
```

Comment: Remove() will not work if there is a non-nullable foreign-key constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this format:

```
context.Entry(temp).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

Remove() only work in DBContext..

Answer (score 0):

In Mvc 5
use RemoveRange instead of DeleteObject while deleting list.

RemoveRange();