# Delete data from datatable via AJAX call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a view where I have AJAX call

Here is code of AJAX request, it's just hit method on back end:

```
<script>
// deleting
$("#send").click(
    function sender() {
        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'Post',
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            url: '@Url.Action("DeleteAll", "Questions")',
            success: function(da) {
                if (da.Result === "Success") {

                    alert("Data deleted!");

                } else {

                    alert('Error' + da.Message);
                }
            },
            error: function(da) {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    });
```

And method on back end

```
public ActionResult DeleteAll()
{
    ApplicationDbContext context =  new ApplicationDbContext();
    List<InvitationMail> query = context.InvitationMails.ToList();
    foreach (InvitationMail q in query)
    {
        context.DeleteObject(q);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
    return Json(new {Result = "Success", Message = "Saved Successfully"});
}
```

But I have this error

[image]

I need to delete all data from  `InvitationMail` table, how I can do this?

Comment: Change DELEteobject(q) to Remove(q); check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763896/cant-call-deleteobject-in-entity-framework-missing-an-assembly-reference

Comment: what error you have got?

Comment: if you have list of id than user 

removerange(query) do not user foreachloop

Comment: [Can't call DeleteObject in Entity framework - missing an assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763896/cant-call-deleteobject-in-entity-framework-missing-an-assembly-reference?noredirect=1&lq=1) please check this link maybe its helpful for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Removerange` function its work much faster than `foreach`:

```
List<InvitationMail> query = context.InvitationMails.ToList();
context.InvitationMails.Removerange(query); 
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`DbContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.103).aspx) doesn't include a `DeleteObject()` method but you can use the `Remove()` method. Something like this:

```
foreach (InvitationMail q in query)
{
    context.InvitationMails.Remove(q); 
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `TRUNCATE TABLE` SQL command like this:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE InvitationMail");
```